# Как вывести виджет твитера или фейсбука?

Tags: drupal, twitter, facebook

Как вывести виджет твитера или фейсбука на сайте CMS Drupal 7 как здесь http://flybike.radugadevelops.ru?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Facebook social plugins integration](https://drupal.org/project/fb_social)

[Drupal for Facebook](https://drupal.org/project/fb)

[Twitter](https://drupal.org/project/twitter)

[Social media](https://drupal.org/project/socialmedia)